# Triangulation of a convex polygon?

Tags: algorithm

Apply greedy algorithm to the problem of the
minimum length triangulation of a convex polygon.

How far can greedy be away from optimum?
Show the worst case for a pentagon.

I am kind of confused about this question. I know A pentagon has 5 sides and thus 3 triangles. But I am not what is meant by greedy is that choosing a side with least length.

And how is this different from the optimal.

Comment: To break a pentagon into three triangle you take any point and draw two lines to the non adjacent points.  If you draw a pentagon with one angle greater than 180 degrees you will find that you can only use the point with the angle greater than 180 degrees to divide the pentagon into 3 triangles.

Comment: An angle greater than 180 would result in a concave polygon, would it not?

Comment: This is just a guess but I would suppose "greedy" here means this: take the pentagon, look at all the adjacent pairs of sides. Pick the pair where connecting the line connecting the two ends is the shortest. Now you've got a triangle and a quadrilateral. You repeat the same process for the quadrilateral.

Comment: @biziclop I think I see what you mean when I do the process you suggested the lenghts I will get will not the shortest and thus not optimal. Thus showing that the greedy algorithm is not the best.

Comment: @jdweng I think the greedy algorithm in mind is to find a diagonal of min length and use that to split the polygon into two halves; apply the algorithm recursively to each (convex) half.

Comment: @EdwardDoolittle This is exactly what I tried to write and failed. :) Yes, that's what I'd consider a greedy algorithm.